# Can Typescript Interfaces express co-occurrence constraints for properties

Tags: typescript, constraints

Is there a standard pattern within a monolithic Typescript Interface or Type definitions to assert properties either appear together or don't appear at all?

For example an item could be valid if it looked like this...

```js
{
  id:"ljklkj",
  spellcheck:true,
  spellcheckModel:"byzantine",
}
```

...or this...

```js
{
  id:"ljklkj",
}
```

However it would be invalid if either of the spellcheck properties occurred in isolation.

```js
{
  id:"ljklkj",
  spellcheckModel:"byzantine",
}
```

```js
{
  id:"ljklkj",
  spellcheck:true,
}
```

**Monolithic**

Of course the simple case above could be resolved by creating a Data and a SpellcheckData Type or Interface. In my application case, however, there will be more than one 'cluster' of co-occurring properties. Defining a new type for every combination of co-occurrence would lead to an explosion of types in order to express the case.

For this reason I've referred to the solution as a 'monolithic' interface. Of course it may be necessary to use some form of composition to define it.

**What I've Tried**

I have tried to find examples like this within the Typescript language reference, but without knowing what the feature might be called, (or indeed if it's a feature that can be expressed at all), I'm struggling. Properties can be individually optional but I can't see a way of expressing co-occurrence.

**Related Technologies**

An equivalent feature for XML data validation is discussed here...
https://www.w3.org/wiki/Co-occurrence_constraints

For JSON I understand schema languages like Schematron and Json Content Rules are able to express co-constraints.

**Worked example**

If I were to imagine typescript syntax for the co-constraint case applied to HTTP parameter sets for the Solr search engine, it might look like this, indicating that you could opt in to fully satisfying the Spell or Group params, or not at all - a union in which each type is optional (indicated by the ***?***) ...

```js
type SolrPassthru =
  SolrCoreParams & (
    SolrSpellParams? |
    SolrGroupParams?  
  )
```

This contrasts with the example below, which is I believe is correct Typescript, but requires ALL parameters from each group of parameters.

```js
type SolrCoreParams = {
  defType: SolrDefType,
  boost: SolrBoostType,
}

type SolrSpellParams = {
  spellcheck: "true" | "false",
  "spellcheck.collate": "true" | "false",
  "spellcheck.maxCollationTries": 1,
}

type SolrGroupParams = {
  group: "true" | "false",
  "group.limit": '4'
  "group.sort": 'group_level asc,score desc,published desc,text_sort asc'
  "group.main": 'true'
  "group.field": 'group_uri'
}

type SolrPassthru =
  SolrCoreParams & 
  SolrSpellParams &
  SolrGroupParams
```

Comment: Weird, [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeAoK6oEMBcUB2ArgLYBGEATgNwoC+UAPsmhjvsWVc+iboaRdQxQAxr3YDa1FMID2eAM7AowAAy44iJFlwBGFVBrVZCpcB3qEybVD0AaKDygAmfYelzFypxc3W7D3Bd7USgAZldKIA) should have worked :/

Comment: Thanks for trying, @NinoFiliu just to clarify I think you're saying it should have FAILED - e.g. the compile should have choked on `const t1: T = { a: 10, b: 20 };` since it was 'in between' the two cases composed in the union.

Comment: Yeah I think that's what he was trying to show. "This should have worked" -> "The compiler should have seen it's not ok"

Comment: Note however that this approach wouldn't extend to the application case described above, which I added to clarify the problem of the combinatorial explosion. A distinct 'type' in the union would have been needed for every COMBINATION of co-occurrence, meaning an explosion of type definitions. There would have had to be a type for where you used Core, another for Core+Spell, another for Core+Group, another for Core+Group+Spell and it would get crazier when you added a third co-occurring parameter group.

Comment: It seems natural to express sets of co-occurent properties as required properties in interfaces and object literal types. I'm not sure what syntax would be easier. Or maybe you're looking for some kind of metaprogramming facility where you can validate that the types you do declare conform to co-occurence rules you specify for types in some scope. You might be able to achieve that with lint rules or language service plugins.

Comment: Thanks, @AluanHaddad indeed for each group of co-occurrent properties it would be required that all properties appear. The trick I was missing was to be able to use generics as a mechanism to derive Optional<T> types from types which themselves DO have required parameters. These transformed types can then be unioned together, and each can only be satisfied when all properties of a type are fulfilled, or none are there.

Comment: @cefn yeah, that's definitely a useful technique and I use it regularly. `Required<T>` is also very powerful.

Comment: Except unfortunately I found it doesn't work - because of "all types assignable to empty interfaces" https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-all-types-assignable-to-empty-interfaces, the empty interface allows any or no fields, so it doesn't constrain anything, which is why @Leziak's approach has to jump through hoops to generate the expected compile errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the following. It seems it shows errors in the correct places.

```
type None<T> = {[K in keyof T]?: never}
type EitherOrBoth<T1, T2> = T1 & None<T2> | T2 & None<T1> | T1 & T2

interface Data {
  id: string;
}

interface SpellCheckData {
  spellcheck: boolean,
  spellcheckModel: string,
}

// Two interfaces
var z1: EitherOrBoth<Data, SpellCheckData> = { id: "" };
var z2: EitherOrBoth<Data, SpellCheckData> = { spellcheck: true,  spellcheckModel: 'm'};
var z3ERROR: EitherOrBoth<Data, SpellCheckData> = { spellcheck: true};
var z4: EitherOrBoth<Data, SpellCheckData> = { id: "", spellcheck: true,  spellcheckModel: 'm'};

interface MoreData {
  p1: string,
  p2: string,
  p3: string,
}

type Monolith = EitherOrBoth<Data, EitherOrBoth<SpellCheckData, MoreData>>

var x1: Monolith  = { id: "" };
var x2: Monolith  = { spellcheck: true,  spellcheckModel: 'm'};
var x3ERROR: Monolith  = { spellcheck: true};                       
var x4: Monolith  = { id: "", spellcheck: true,  spellcheckModel: 'm'};
var x5ERROR: Monolith  = { p1: ""};                                  
var x6ERROR: Monolith  = { p1: "", p2: ""};
var x7: Monolith  = { p1: "", p2: "", p3: ""};
var x8: Monolith  = { id: "", p1: "", p2: "", p3: ""};
var x9ERROR: Monolith  = { id: "", spellcheck: true, p1: "", p2: "", p3: ""};
var x10: Monolith  = { id: "", spellcheck: true, spellcheckModel: 'm', p1: "", p2: "", p3: ""};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOwgHgCoD4oF4oG8DaA0lAJYJQDWEIcAZlKgLoD8AXFEgG4QBOAvgFgAUKEhQAoiWAALXgHkeAITgy0ARgA0DAEyYcqNVABksRClS6oAHx3HTSdZhsG7F4cLLBetAIYBjaAARH2AfPGEoUgATdgBnYB4yAHMAbmFBIQ8ELx5fAKgAZUgAG2KAYVk-CmDQ8KFI2JLiv0qKdgAjODhiiB8EDQioRohSlogqgFk4KJG4hOSBoQzhAHoVhgB3OFJs738IWOFOHx4oAC81dkkZeSUVaWQany0ikfLWp708aPYAIl+oHw0kJjqcztorlJZDwFMpVE8Xk0KuNqiEfF9cEMmmMquwEgBXCBaLFvHEUKYzYrsADkAFtqUCjidzgBmcQAJXZcnZkJuMLu8LRiLeyKqn2w32Go1aeJ4hMZIOZZwALLzobD7o8hYUkR80RiflB-lopc0ZVACUSGtjWhTZlA6QzgVkcnloFMeBAnnVImBLkN5ggkotfRCA4kgyGoGAWXMI8H0u4ROB3YhulCJdd1QKHgiJFDbnCHq9SqLUaEtB6vfr0EnQVAAB7+qYIdMySI4TEkGJGgEK+sNsMttvSDuSm0o2WE4mmsl2qkO+n95kNtmc7nsYfFDMSzGz82WoGRY8n09n49M04N1VQLc7zuG40k6WTi1yq3Ps0o+c0pfAgcAKwclyPK3mm27tru0b+v8R7nvBCEIZejYAGzARuYGthBo5QX6fy-FoYBhrB-4rgA7Ju4H3t8eG9oRxEEdGsa9suV4AByUVh1Fdj2T60XxDGEcxJHIQ2ACc6GgXekEPt2+EmhOuJvtO0HydGglMfhrGNmoAAMnEjmOPFqfur6WgppK2tM9qOoRMGMURakxlpKRAA)

**Update**

If you prefer to pass types as a tuple, you can use the following utility:

```
type CombinationOf<T> = T extends [infer U1, infer U2] ? EitherOrBoth<U1, U2> :
                        T extends [infer U1, infer U2, infer U3] ? EitherOrBoth<U1, EitherOrBoth<U2, U3>> :
                        T extends [infer U1, infer U2, infer U3, infer U4] ? EitherOrBoth<U1, EitherOrBoth<U2, EitherOrBoth<U3, U4>>> :
                        never;

type Monolith = CombinationOf<[Data, SpellCheckData, MoreData]>
```

If some properties are required:

```
type Monolith = Data & CombinationOf<[Data, SpellCheckData, MoreData]>
```

Comment: Crazy-cool. The 'binary tree' has a tendency towards making 'christmas trees', it definitely does the job. Some way to compose 0-n type definitions rather than having to compose them pairwise would be great. The approach has the limitation that all co-occurrence rules have to have distinct keys. I rewrote it for my own comprehension and ended up with this when joining three co-occurrence groups `type SolrParams = EitherOrBoth<CoreParams,EitherOrBoth<FacetParams,EitherOrBoth<SpellParams, GroupParams>>>`

Comment: See update. This is the best I can do, but maybe someone more knowledgable than me can improve it further.

Comment: Thanks, @Lesiak the more I look into this the more it appears that with your generics wrapper plus union approach I could make this radically simpler. If I define `type Optional<T> = {} | T` that allows me to compose clusters like `type SolrParams = CoreParams & Optional<SpellParams> & Optional<FacetParams> & Optional<GroupParams>;` Thanks so much for setting me in the right direction.

Comment: Also think about segregating your properties and flattening them at the boundary, instead of using a monolithic type. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.0-beta#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAsAKGWWABMAuZAZzClAHMBuAgXwINElkRQGUAHCABtBAYQAWEBAGt0mHASKUBwhBOkUARgHstgiHBAAaBVWWDVkqQFktJIRWq0QdY-lb524aPCTIbUCFksPEJkPgBGBxp6VyI+ACYopxcTPgBmJJiWNnwOb25kHgg6ALoMCBIABSgtPkp5UNJM51jTIIB+Cn4hUTUZDDhWgFstAI6Kf0CB7I98BC0QamQYLuLS8qqauuQAXgaiJuQAcnCj1qUgihCiRTMLdWQaAFcIVtue++tbe2Oho5N3O4CPNFmBloIMJAQBVdvtiORlgA6UitRFomCIi4DVHoxEjMbTNw5IA

Comment: I'm afraid your Optional type is not strong enough: `type Monolith =  Data & Optional<SpellCheckData> & Optional<MoreData>
var x2: Monolith  = { id: "" , spellcheck: true};` should be flagged but is not.

Comment: Yes, @Lesiak - just discovering that and not sure how to force the strictness I would expect. It's as if once you've put something through a union, anything goes.

Comment: Separating out the param groups and composing them at runtime is the next most realistic alternative. I can in principle introduce runtime logic but a shame to have to. Opt-in features as part of Solr HTTP requests like https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_6/result-grouping.html are implemented through passing named values in a HTTP param map. These named params are inherently coupled to each other, yet seems hard to use typescript to enforce validity of the map (e.g. ensure that you have group=true among your parameters if you expect group.limit to have any effect).