# TypeScript: Optional merge types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have type `a` and type `b`, but this should work with any amount of types.

```
type a = {
    first: number
}

type b = {
    second: string
    third: string
}
```

I want to create a type that optionally merges all those types, so if it would have the `second` field, it should have the `third` field also, but it doesn't have to have them both:

Good:

```
const aa = {
     first: 1,
     second: "hi",
     third: "hello"
}

const ab = {
     first: 1
}

const ac = {
     second: "hi",
     third: "hello"
}
```

Bad:

```
const bb = {
     first: 1,
     second: "hi"
}
```

How could I define such a type?

Comment: Are you looking for XOR merging?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
type None<T> = {[K in keyof T]?: never}
type EitherOrBoth<T1, T2> = T1 & None<T2> | T2 & None<T1> | T1 & T2

type abcombined = EitherOrBoth<a,b>
```

See more elaborated example at: [Can Typescript Interfaces express co-occurrence constraints for properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63446889/can-typescript-interfaces-express-co-occurrence-constraints-for-properties/63447495#63447495)

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAhlC8UDeAoK6oDMCWAnAzsAFxQB2ArgLYBGEuKAviiqJFNQsmhvhAMYB7UgBMShXNlIBzbumAALPKKjjJMpi3DQAckIgAeACoA%20TkgDaAaSiSoAawggBmKIYC6AfhKkIANzpMrNAAotgKdADyuABCAgpGAIwANK4ATKaIhglQAGRQuj5G6VAAPmm5%20XqJpmVZFYapzJpsMNSCNJIQwpyh4bhRsfEwKdTGANzMgqSEsDAkre3Und2IqBjoOATEUMmy6LxTygBEikdJe1AKSiQnEAA2dwJHjJNCM63zbQIdPitc61g8IQSAkXigpu8%20J9FsszBcDkJjqdzgCrrgkfdHs8NBDgOxqNDvktfnCAZtgTsUesESIbqcXkA)

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! Just can the EitherOrBoth type be applied to more than two types?

Comment: Yes, you can pass another EitherOrBoth as a type argument. Check linked questions for example.

Comment: Thank you! This solves my problem. I've checked the linked question, could the `CombinationOf` type be applied to any number of types?

Comment: The definition in linked question has up to four types, but it is easy to extend it if you need more.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you could do that. This is what I would do :

You could use "|" operator while defining a variable.

```
type a = {
    first: number
}

type b = {
    second: string
    third: string
}

const test: a | b ={ first: 3, second: 'string'}
```