# How to map tuple of types (of arbitrary length) to nested type using recursive conditional types

Tags: typescript

In my answer to [Can Typescript Interfaces express co-occurrence constraints for properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63446889/can-typescript-interfaces-express-co-occurrence-constraints-for-properties) I produced following code:

```
type None<T> = {[K in keyof T]?: never}
type EitherOrBoth<T1, T2> = T1 & None<T2> | T2 & None<T1> | T1 & T2

type CombinationOf<T> = T extends [infer U1, infer U2] ? EitherOrBoth<U1, U2> :
                        T extends [infer U1, infer U2, infer U3] ? EitherOrBoth<U1, EitherOrBoth<U2, U3>> :
                        T extends [infer U1, infer U2, infer U3, infer U4] ? EitherOrBoth<U1, EitherOrBoth<U2, EitherOrBoth<U3, U4>>> :
                        never;

type Monolith = CombinationOf<[Data1, Data2, Data3]>
```

Currently, `CombinationOf` handles tuple of type arguments, up to four elements.
While this can be trivially extended, I wonder if, with the advent of [recursive conditional types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40002), type `CombinationOf` can be expressed in more elegant way.

Thus, my questions are:

- Can I use recursive conditional types to map tuple of types (of arbitrary length) to nested type?
- If so, is there any depth limit for recursion? (Hopefully this is only theoretical problem)
- How can I prove to myself that new type generated with recursive conditional type is equivalent to my existing code?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOwgHgCoD4oF4oG8DaA0lAJYJQDWEIcAZlKgLoD8AXFEgG4QBOAvgChQkKAFESwABa8A8jwBCcKWgCMAGgYAmTDlQqoAMliIUqbVAA%20Ww8aSrMVvTbMCh4aAGE4AWwBGZAENgEkQZWjQdBigIAA9gCAQAEwBnKHwyWl4oAFV1UgRMnhzNRihmMQlpHjlFZVyNbPNWAShWtvaOzrbUaLiElLSMrPr8wuKNIaLsgGZS8vEpWQUlSWQRhaqalbXNBun0TGau45Oe2Pik1PSC4bzJ8dHh6YmbqYAWOYrF6uW6vI2lrVVo0NACfkC1s8cm8DocWicEe0uLwANyuMjxHi0AIAY2gABEggF9Lh4SREuxksAeGQAOZowQCDG8bF4qCE4ABTR4eHJSAAG35OOkOIo7F8cDg-IgAQQal5AqFIooAFk4IkIPzKdS6fLGcysbiCUTpjzWmAVNqaQhafLzZorbr4WBpo6bXrXMJoGqEFLKtycF4-IFgqFwvgOcSNJHduyTYx0EA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TypeScript 4.1 when recursive conditional types are introduced, you should be able to define `CombinationOf<T>` like this:

```
type CombinationOf<T> =
  T extends [infer U1, ...infer R] ? (
    R extends [] ? never : EitherOrBoth<U1,
      R extends [infer U2] ? U2 : CombinationOf<R>
    >
  ) : never;
```

Here I've tried to stick as close as possible to your original definition without worrying about what the `EitherOrBoth<>` type is supposed to really be doing.  Note that because your original definition returns `never` when `T` is a one-element tuple, the definition here is a little more compilcated.  (I'd sort of expect `CombinationOf<[X]>` to just be `X`.  But ‍♂️)

If `T` has 0 or 1 elements, you get `never`.  If there are two elements, you get `EitherOrBoth<U1, U2>` where `U1` and `U2` are the first two elements of `T`.  Otherwise, you get `EitherOrBoth<U1, CombinationOf<R>>` where `R` is the rest/tail of the tuple `T` after `U1`.

---

Yes, there is a depth limit and it's not very deep; something like 10 levels:

```
type TestDepth = CombinationOf<[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]> // works for me
type TestDepthBad = CombinationOf<[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]> // error, too deep
```

You can probably rewrite `CombinationOf` to look more like your original version where it chops the tuple `T` into groups of 3 or 4 instead of groups of 1 and get the depth limit to increase (maybe to 30 or 40... edit: playing around with this I can't seem to get it to go above 25 or so) at the expense of an even more complicated `CombinationOf`.  Not sure it's worth it, though.

---

Proving that the types are the same could either be done by just inspecting the definitions of this `CombinationOf` and yours (which I'll call `CombinationOfOrig`), or by building an inspector type function:

```
type IfEquals<T, U, Y = unknown, N = never> =
  (<G>() => G extends T ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<G>() => G extends U ? 1 : 2) ? Y : N;
type TestEqualCombinationOf<T> = 
  IfEquals<CombinationOfOrig<T>, CombinationOf<T>, "Same", "Oops">;
```

Here, `IfEquals<T, U, Y, N>` will evaluate to `Y` if the compiler sees `T` and `U` as identical types, and `N` otherwise.  See [this comment in GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-421529650) for more info about this type equality operator.

And `TestEqualCombinationOf<T>` will evaluate to `"Same"` if `CombinationOfOrig<T>` is identical to `CombinationOf<T>`, and `"Oops"` otherwise.  Here are the results of the tests:

```
type TestEmpty = TestEqualCombinationOf<[]> // Same
type TestSingleton = TestEqualCombinationOf<[Data1]> // Same
type TestPair = TestEqualCombinationOf<[Data1, Data2]>; // Same
type TestTriple = TestEqualCombinationOf<[Data1, Data2, Data3]>; // Same
interface Data4 { four: 4 }
type TestQuadruple = TestEqualCombinationOf<[Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4]>; // Same

interface Data5 { five: 5 }
type TestQuintuple = TestEqualCombinationOf<[Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4, Data5]>; // Oops
```

So experimentally, at least, the two definitions are the same for any tuple up to length 4.  I was actually a bit worried about `TestQuintuple` being `"Oops"` until I remembered that the original definition only worked for tuples of length up to 4.  So that `"Oops"` is expected.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200915#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHAjMg3gKGWWABMAuZAZzClAHMBufAX331ElkRXUwCY8hKgAcIAGzEIAFhAQBrCgCMA9srEQ4IADRDKoidNlyAsspLiK1WiDo7W7cNHhI0GOAGZBRYVks16Ot58fta2QsLuIQEsbGAAnqLIAMLKALaKoBjAyiAA8jC5tHQAPAAqAHzIALzIpcgQAB6QICSUyADaoDDQyACqWFrEIN1QfXwAusgA-MgAosBgMlCFAELKi8X9g718lWRCdY3NrR1dPVtDI2ODZ6O97pMz84vQq+tSmwNzC0tvGzvbdzlPYHepNCAtNqdYbnL63a6Xc7uG4wu4AFke3xeyyga3+X2ev1x702fEGhNexP+yL6aOBIKIIAgADdoEx8PFEqYQGoftVkmkMiAsjl8oVgCV2rxsINpWTXJgHuU2ByEigAHI5CBlSo1XAdADSQ2QcggcWUMFq4ymFCZrNGrE5KApOLxH1KX1Ku35HuQADJkJqmWVvQAfWoCANB7Ueyrh30Br2xNUC9KZMDZPIwHXVUFHCEnaFXC4AOjL8IASpiABRCIgVsHHKGYu09Cguv4fLZ1ojIBv5yGnVFjTE7ZAUFJp4UZ0XZivK3vIBfIACU4+Qrag7KdyG5vMWAhqk6FIqzxSlbi+ctlbiVKp3pQg1FQEGEi35x-Tmfy56+8ppaKDAArIMABsgwAOyDAAHIMACc4yVAA9EhyAAO7KFAchtDAmHIKkECqokj7Pq+iwrHAJAfoKX6zr+gz-oMgHICByDgcgUHILByBwYMWAAAyIcgKH1FAUCYYMYCqMg5ivveKYAJIwLMACOACucBiJQZTbIMACa-JqSAcg8mh2iBvym66kI1bFAA4uU1ZrlUlR2Y2BZtHUMw4BQfBrgOrQ2fZjnOa57mDr00zID5yB+VFBkUOqTAPk+YCqRpYiftO37ZhU-JKelmnaVlp5ikUOqDCVM5nhUgwAEQAMpwARdX1bkyjCJQdXlNuKYkWlqRvnEPqpYVmU0dldHtEJIlNQRREoP1DX0OoUkgCN1BjVVOXntKWAzahc2ESl1AAApwMAow1P1W0TaV2YXpgV5uBMPXCYdzXHX1qWlLQwjqBtaXqZp21TXtN78BDHiIQw73IEdDicM4PBuGieDILhalQBQaOOt91AAIoaSQUBqf9KDXaNwPjVO927ZeUPytKNLShib2zZ9bAcE43AKnAQHozAwCshQAt48RqVExwZMA5Tm3U6DZ6PTKfNM7eUPMdKQEw3D7WdfgQA)